# FTP issue on Windows 10. Works if u connect two devices directly with ethernet cable but not through a router

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, router, ftp

Im trying to share files with ftp(media, documents etc).I got a laptop which works perfectly fine with ftp on my network. I can connect it with my pc with only an ethernet cable.

1. All devices on my network connected through ethernet/wifi can connect with each other excluding my windows 10 pc. My pc cant connect to them, they cant connect to it

   2. If i USB Tether my phones internet, my phone connected to my wifi network. It works flawlessly like in other devices.
   3. Disabled firewalls, made port exceptions both in windows firewall and the router.
   4. Got a different hard drive and installed the latest Ubuntu version 20.04. Same problem. It works if i plug it directly with an ethernet cable but not through the network

Could this be a hardware problem?!

My ethernet port is a "Intel(R) 82567LM-3 Gigabit Network Connection".
Please help. :(

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. What are you thethering to what in point 2) and how does that relate to 1). FTP from where to where? Please edit your question and add more detail. As it stands it will be closed for  "unclear what you are asking"

Comment: This does not sound like a hardware issue. It sounds to me to most likely be a router/firewall issue.

Comment: @Tonny my pc on its own (connected to ethernet directly to router) ftp doesnt work. If i disable my ethernet, connect my phone. Tether its internet to my pc and use that as a way to use internet. Ftp works. Ftp works on all devices either way. The pc is the only loose end, with exception of direct ethernet cable or if i tether my phones internet :/